# Commands under a cog don’t show up

Tags: python, discord.py

So when I wrote this code, I checked commands.py for all indents and they were correct but for some reason when I run the code, only the help command which is outside of the cog shows up in discord. Am I doing something wrongly here? There aren’t any errors in the terminal unless I use the command in discord. Then it says `Ignoring exception in command None: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command “{command}" is not found`

main.py

```
for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
  if filename.endswith(".py"):
    client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}”)
```

In ./cogs/commands.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
import pafy
import asyncio

class Commands(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
    self.song_queue = {}

  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_ready(self):
    for guild in self.client.guilds():
      self.song_queue[guild.id] = []
    print("Cogs are cogging")
  @commands.command()
  #example command, same indents as the actual code
  async def ping(self, ctx):
    return await ctx.send("PONG")

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(Commands(client))
```

Comment: why do you have `class Commands(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client` defined twice? and import modules twice

Comment: You also open and close strings with `”` instead of `"` in your print statements

Comment: Sorry i wrote it wrongly in stackoverflow but in my IDE it was written correctly

Comment: The error is outside of the code you shared. The code you shared works fine on its own (excluding the `( )` around after guilds in `self.client.guilds()`. Please include the code where ever you have this `{command}` declared.

Comment: hm ok ill try searching the rest of my code for errors, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is outside of the code you shared. The code you shared works fine on its own (excluding the `( )` around after `guilds` in `self.client.guilds()`. Please include the code where ever you have this `{command}` declared

-lemon.py